# Difference between '()' or '(otherModule)' before module close and after module close in javaScript

Tags: javascript

I'm new in javaScript modules. I read many articles for that, and find Modules are defined by two different ways below:

```
// '()' after module close
var firstModule = (function() {
  // Module defination goes here
})();

// '()' before module close
var secondModule = (function() {
  // Module definition goes here
}());
```

I try both and not find any difference.

Please reply what is the difference between both, and in which case we've to use which type of declaration?

Answer (score 2):

There's no difference in practice. It's just about preference, you can even write it like this:

```
var f = function(){ ... }();
```

The parenthesis around it are meant to warn you that the function is an IIFE (Immediately Invoked Function Expression). On the first example you treat only the function as an expression. On the second one you treat the whole IIFE as an expression. There's no difference on how the code will run it's just there to give you that clue.